# Entity Framework update model from database issue

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am working on a project that was compiled and executed pretty fine before updating the Entity Framework model from the database. After updating I get errors like that:

```
<project> does not contain a definition for 'SaveChanges'
<project> does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteStoreQuery'
```

But there is a reference to `System.Data.Entity` in my project. What actually I have done with database I've only added few columns to table.

What is the reason for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. From the designer view select all models delete and then give a Update Model From Database.
Worked for me.